# Plotting US Map with ggplot2 for some states only

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

I have the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsn) # for scale bar `scalebar`
library(fiftystater)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data= data.to.work.african, aes(map_id = State_L)) + 
ggtitle("African American") +
geom_map(aes(fill = Suicide_Rate_By_Pop),  color= "white", map = fifty_states) + 
expand_limits(x = fifty_states$long, y = fifty_states$lat) +
coord_map() +
geom_text(data = fifty_states %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          summarise(lat = mean(c(max(lat), min(lat))),
                    long = mean(c(max(long), min(long)))) %>%
          mutate(State_L = id) %>%
          left_join(data.to.work.african, by = "State_L"),  size=2, 
          aes(x = long, y = lat, label = paste(Acronym, Suicide_Rate_By_Pop, sep = '\n'))
         ) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
labs(x = "", y = "") + 
labs(fill = "Suicides Rate by 100,000 inhabitants")+
  
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)),na.value="grey90",
                     guide = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 25, barheight = 0.4,
                                             #put legend title on top of legend
                                             title.position = "top")
                                            ) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.title=element_text(size=10), 
      legend.text=element_text(size=08))
```

and the result is:
[image]

In my data set I did not have information for all states, because this, some states on map present the 'NA' result and has not line around it's own area.

How I would fix this problem? I would like to present the name of state for that one that has no line on my data set, like MT.

### Data

```
# The data extracted from dput is:
structure(list(Acronym = c("AL", "AK", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", 
"DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", 
"MD", "MA", "MI", "MS", "MO", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NY", "NC", 
"OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "TN", "TX", "VA", "WA", "WI"
), State_U = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arkansas", "California", 
"Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", 
"Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
"Michigan", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Nebraska", "Nevada", 
"New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New York", "North Carolina", 
"Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"Wisconsin"), State_L = c("alabama", "alaska", "arkansas", "california", 
"colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "district of columbia", 
"florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", 
"kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maryland", "massachusetts", 
"michigan", "mississippi", "missouri", "nebraska", "nevada", 
"new hampshire", "new jersey", "new york", "north carolina", 
"ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", 
"south carolina", "tennessee", "texas", "virginia", "washington", 
"wisconsin"), Race = c("African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American", "African American", "African American", "African American", 
"African American"), Suicide_Rates = c(14L, 1L, 4L, 42L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 33L, 2L, 20L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 21L, 20L, 6L, 
23L, 14L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 27L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 1L, 24L, 3L, 
9L, 13L, 40L, 24L, 7L, 2L), Population = c(4452173L, 627963L, 
2678588L, 33987977L, 4326921L, 3411777L, 786373L, 572046L, 16047515L, 
8227303L, 1213519L, 12434161L, 6091866L, 2929067L, 2693681L, 
4049021L, 4471885L, 5311034L, 6361104L, 9952450L, 2848353L, 5607285L, 
1713820L, 2018741L, 1239882L, 8430621L, 19001780L, 8081614L, 
11363543L, 3454365L, 3429708L, 12284173L, 1050268L, 4024223L, 
5703719L, 20944499L, 7105817L, 5910512L, 5373999L), Suicide_Rate_By_Pop = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.124, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.162, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.191, 0, 
NA, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 28L, 
30L, 34L, 38L, 44L, 48L, 51L, 54L, 58L, 61L, 65L, 69L, 73L, 80L, 
84L, 88L, 92L, 96L, 99L, 106L, 110L, 116L, 119L, 123L, 127L, 
131L, 133L, 138L, 142L, 150L, 153L, 158L), class = "data.frame")

#  I read it's .csv using
data.to.work.african  <- read.csv2("dataSuicideAfrican.csv", sep = ';', 
                                stringsAsFactors=FALSE,  
                                header = TRUE)
```

Comment: To bets assist you, can you please share the data from `data.to.work.african` using something like `dput(data.to.work.african)`?

Comment: Shared here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZCJThspQkPMw-5dn5n-qAw-smLS36S6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: We dont have the data `fifty_states` in the `geom_map` command - also, all the values in your `Suicide_Rate_By_Pop` are `0`  (and one `NA`), is this correct? It does not reconcile with your plot image

Comment: That is wrong, fifty_states is on fiftystater package

By the way need  to load thisp packages:

library(ggplot2)
library(ggsn) # for scale bar `scalebar`
library(fiftystater)
library(tidyverse)

Comment: Please edit your question to include these dependencies. Again, though, in the data you provided in the link, all 50 states have a `0` value for `Suicide_Rate_By_Pop` except one. The `fiftystater` wont load on current versions of `r`. It would be much better if you provided these data in the question using `dput()`

Comment: I edited the question.
About the data, I have values only for 4 states: CA, FL, NY and TX.
Dput generates a very long text that it is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `ggplot` code per se, rather the data. In the `geom_text` part of the `ggplot` the labels return `NA` because  your current `data.to.work.african` data have only 39 states, and the `fifty_states` data has 51. You can overcome this by:

1. Identifying the missing states using `setdiff()`
2. Adding these state names to your `State_L` column in `data.to.work.african` dataset
3. Converting state names to acronyms using `state.abb()` function

The rerun your code and all good!

Code:

```
# Find missing states
missing_states <- setdiff(unique(fifty_states$id), data.to.work.african$State_L)

#> missing_states
# [1] "arizona"       "idaho"         "maine"         "minnesota"     "montana"       "new mexico"   
# [7] "north dakota"  "south dakota"  "utah"          "vermont"       "west virginia" "wyoming"  

# add missing states to `data.to.work.african` dataset
currows <- nrow(data.to.work.african) # current number of rows

# add state names
data.to.work.african[(currows+1):(currows + length(missing_states)),"State_L"] <- missing_states

# add acronyms
data.to.work.african[(currows+1):(currows + length(missing_states)),"Acronym"] <- state.abb[match(missing_states,tolower(state.name))]
```

Rerunning your code:

[image]

Note that the `fiftystater` package is not available for current versions of R, but the `fifty_states` data can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/fiftystater/blob/master/data/fifty_states.rda)

Comment: Just cautioning that state.abb does include DC